# Setting relative links

Tags: django

I just bought from a marketplace a template for my site. The thing is that this template has relative links to its resources (styles, images, scripts, etc). Of course, all the links are currently broken. My question is: what could be the best approach to fix these links?.

I don't thing that setting all the links to {{ STATIC_URL }} be a good idea since this template has **a lot** of files, resources and links.

Note: When I say "template" I'm meaning a folder with a lot of HTML, CSS and images files.

Thanks in advance!

Update:

This is how my problem looks: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gbtfjaaaqxw7coo/error.png

Comment: It should render fine. Just update your `TEMPLATE_DIRS` to accomodate the template folder, and the relative links should work they are

Comment: karthikr, I don't have problem rendering HTML files. My problem is with the resources (static files) included in those HTMLs. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough before

Comment: Have you tried it out? My feeling is, It should not be a problem.

Comment: I tried adding the parent of the folder where the static files are and I'm still having the same behavior. This [1] will illustrate much better my problem.

[1] https://www.dropbox.com/s/gbtfjaaaqxw7coo/error.png

Answer (score 1):

Solved, I just added to my urls.py this:

```
urlpatterns += patterns(
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.views',
    url(r'assets/(?P<path>.*)$', 'serve'),
)
```

And set `STATIC_URL = 'assets/'`